# Linq where clause not filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda, where-clause

Anyone could tell why this code runs properly:

```
EmployeeContextDataContext empContext = new EmployeeContextDataContext();

var departaments = empContext.Departments.Where(x => x.Name == "IT" || x.Name=="HR");

foreach (Department dept in departaments)
        {
         Response.Write(dept.Name);

         var empInDept = dept.Employees;

         foreach (var employee in empInDept)
            {
            Response.Write(employee.FirstName + employee.Gender);
            }
        }
```

And the moment I add .Where( x =>  x.Gender == "Male"); it doesnt throw anything at the screen ?

```
foreach (Department dept in departaments)
        {
        Response.Write(dept.Name);

        var empInDept = dept.Employees.Where(x => x.Gender =="Male");

        foreach (var employee in empInDept)
            {
            Response.Write(employee.FirstName);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Because you don't have any male employees....

Comment: Is `Gender` a string?  Have you looked at `employee` before filtering to make sure that some actually have that value?

Comment: @JustinPihony Just not in IT or HR. :)

Comment: Yes, the gender is a string, and the table is populated with Male and Female records, the odd thing is that it works perfectly well before the filtering of gender (1st code snippet), but the moment I add the restriction it doesnt show them anymore (2nd code snippet).

Comment: If you are sure there are "Male" employees, then try making x.Gender.ToString().ToLowerCase() == "male" to make sure you will not fail for case inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain you have male employees in IT or HR?

If you do, are you certain that the Gender column has the M capitalized?

Try removing the case-sensitivity:

```
var empInDept = dept.Employees.Where(x => x.Gender.ToLower().Trim() == "male");
```

Comment: Thank you Matthew, .Trim() did the job, seems the db had some white spaces in the gender column :(, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a breakpoint *inside* the `x.Gender =="Male"` expression to step through it.